# Meaning of "against"

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese

I have a question about the meaning of "against" in the following sentence:

"These communications should be in writing and delivered against receipt."

I don't understand why "against" is used here or what it exactly means.

I'd appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: That is *business English* and means: in exchange for a receipt. It comes from accounting. Items are charged against some other item in accounting.

Comment: @Lambie I'm pretty sure you're right. Have you a reference to support this unusual usage?

Comment: Consider “ Each futures exchange has specific delivery and storage requirements that must be met. For example, at the CME, exchange-approved warehouses are the only entities and locations that can deliver against a futures contract.” From Investopedia.

Answer (score 1):

**against** (prep.)

This meaning of *against* is quite old: the OED's first citation is *c*1225.

> In exchange for, in return for; as an equivalent or set-off for; in
> lieu of, instead of.
>
> 1957   H. Roosenburg *Walls came tumbling Down* 19   We were intended
> as exchanges **against** some high-ranking Nazis.
>
> 1997   D. Mernagh-Ward & J. *Cartwright Good Pract. in Salon Managem.*
> v. 106   A voucher redeemable **against** services during a quiet period
> of the year may be offered. (OED)

> In exchange for
>
> *a lower rate **against** the dollar* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/against)

---

> ... but where there is a promise **against** a promise, one promise is
> the consideration of the other, because each may have his action
> against the other for non-performance. [*The English Reports: King's
> Bench*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_English_Reports_King_s_Bench_1378_18/uH5MAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22promise%20against%20a%20promise%22&pg=PA1271&printsec=frontcover) (1888)

> Payment system. Most oriental carpet import transactions are paid for by cash either
> **against** receipt of the bill of lading or on arrival of the carpet lot.
> [*Markets for Oriental Carpets, vol. 1*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%20Most%20oriental%20carpet%20import%20transactions%20%22) (1969)

> The 1976 Act laid down procedures for the release of bonded labourers
> and specified that no labour could be promised in lieu of payment of
> debt and correspondingly no advances could be given **against** a
> promise of labour. [Anti-Slavery International; *Enslaved Peoples in
> the 1990s*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Enslaved_Peoples_in_the_1990s/cKJFcwregWYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22given%20against%20a%20promise%22&pg=PA123&printsec=frontcover)  (1997)

> The petitioner addressed a letter to Livingstone directing that the
> Treasury notes be delivered to Seaboard **against** payment by that
> company of $9,914,212.71. [*Report of the Tax Court of the US*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Reports_of_the_Tax_Court_of_the_United_S/npMYAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22against%20payment%22&pg=PA1180&printsec=frontcover)
> (1959)

Answer (score 0):

In the example sentence "against" is a preposition and against the conventional meaning here it comes to suggest the meaning of       " next to and touching or being supported by (something)Cf.

It would save space if we put the bed against the wall. (dictionary.cambridge.org)

So "against" here goes to mean "supported by".

Comment: This use, prepositional of course, is something by way of comparison. You are comparing two things:
You must weigh the benefits against the cost;
Check your receipts against the statement;
What's the rate of exchange against the dollar? Against is to mean virsus here and  you are asked to tally properly.

Comment: Delivering x against receipt means: in exchange for a receipt.

Comment: Yes, against here means 'in lieu of' like 'delivery against receipt' or 'cash against delivery'. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a definition of *against* from AHD that may suit your purposes:

> 10. To the account or debt of: drew a check against my bank balance. https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=against

Consider “ Each futures exchange has specific delivery and storage requirements that must be met. For example, at the CME, exchange-approved warehouses are the only entities and locations that can deliver against a futures contract.” From Investopedia.

An alternative to “against” here would be *in response to the presentation of.*